# Upsert in Postgres and auto increment column

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, upsert

I'm trying to find out how to do a correct upsert in postgres into a table which has an auto increment primary key column called "id" and a unique key on the column "name".

The issue is that the source and destination tables are on 2 separate machines, so i have no easy way of knowing what the latest "id" is on the destination table.

The way I am doing it right now is importing the data from the destination table into the source one, checking for the highest "id", updating the table in the source database and then doing the upsert into the destination table, but as you can see, it seems over complicated.

An example of what I want to do is:

**Source table:**

```
id status name
1    ok   John
2    open Monica
```

**Destination table:**

```
id status name
.     .     .
.     .     .
44   ok   David
45   open John
```

**Result of the upsert:**

```
id status name
.     .     .
.     .     .
44   ok   David
45   ok   John
46   open Monica
```

A simple upsert will have duplicate key conflict due to the "id" column.

Comment: why dont you just insert (status, name ) without id, so sequence would take care of id?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the destination side, create a foreign table for the source table with postgres_fdw.

Then you can use a regular

```
INSERT INTO dest (status, name)
   SELECT status, name FROM foreign_source
   ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
   SET status = EXCLUDED.status,
       name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

This requires a unique constraint on `status` or `name` or both.

Comment: thanks, it seems i actually had an issue with my sequence, but i set this as an answer since it may help anyone with a similar question the importance of not using id in the insert values